# Why "sum of squared Pearson residuals" is around "number of dependent variables" in Binomial distribution?

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, residuals

A Pearson residual is defined as:
$r_{i}(\theta)=\frac{y_{i}-E(y_{i}|\theta)}{\sqrt{Var(y_{i}|\theta)}}\tag{1}$
Sum of squared standard residuals $X^{2}$ is:
$X^{2}=\sum_ir_i^2\tag{2}$
where $y_{i}$ is $i$th random variable ($i$ = 1, 2, ..., N). $\theta$ is also a random variable since it's about Bayesian inference, but this particular question is about "given $\theta$", so I think we can think $\theta$ not "random". N is the number of dependent variables y.

In a binomial model `y[i] ~ dbin(theta, n[i])`, it is said that

> for known $\theta$, we might expect $X^{2}$ to be around N.

For an example in **Appendix A**, we can expect $X^{2}$ to be 12, given the known posterior $\theta$ = 0.12 (median value). The prior distribution of $\theta$ is uniform. $i$ has the value of `1, 2, 3, ..., 12` because there are twelve hospitals.

**The problem** is:

I can prove $X^{2}\approx 12$ through simulation in R, as shown in **Appendix B**. However, I do not know how to prove mathmatically:

> $E(X^{2})=N$

**Appendix A:**

The Table below shows data representing the mortality rates from 12 English hospitals carrarying out heart surgery on children between 1991 and 1995.

`Hospital`  `Operations` $n_{i}$  `Deaths` $y_{i}$

```
Bristol  143 41
Leicester 187 25 
Leeds 323 24
Oxford 122 23
Guys 164 25
Liverpool 405 42
Southampton 239 24
Great Ormond St 482 53
Newcastle 195 26
Harefield 177 25 
Birmingham 581 58
Brompton 301 31
```

We can use WinBUGS to calculate the posterior distribution of `theta`, whose median is 0.12.

```
# WinBUGS code
model {
    for (i in 1:12){
        y[i] ~ dbin(theta, n[i])
    }
    theta ~ dunif(0, 1)
}

# Data:
list(y=c(41,25,24,23,25,42,24,53,26,25,58,31),
     n=c(143,187,323,122,164,405,239,482,195,177,581,301))
```

**Appendix B:**

R codes are used to prove that in the example in Appendix A, for known $\theta$ (i.e., 0.12) we might expect sum of squared standard residuals to be total number of hospitals (i.e., 12).

```
# number of hospital
N_hosp <- 12  
# theta's value is from posterior mode to 
# check what "we might expect" for known theta
theta <- 0.12 
# number of operations in ith hospital
n=c(143,187,323,122,164,405,239,482,195,177,581,301)
# number of observed deaths in ith hospital
y=c(41,25,24,23,25,42,24,53,26,25,58,31)
# expected y for known theta
y_expect <- array(dim = c(N_hosp))
# Pearson residual
res <- array(dim = c(N_hosp))
res2 <- array(dim = c(N_hosp))

# sample from Binomial to simulate deaths that "we might expect"
# calculate sum of squared stand. residuals
cal_SRes2 <- function(){
  for (i in 1:N_hosp) {
  y_expect[i] <- rbinom(1,n[i],theta)
  res[i] <- (y_expect[i] - n[i]*theta)/sqrt(n[i]*theta*(1-theta))
  res2[i] <- res[i]*res[i]
}
# sum of squared residuals
  sum(res2)
}

# run 50000 times to see if "sum(res2)" is around 12
tmp <- 0
for (j in 1:50000) {
  tmp <- tmp + cal_SRes2()
}
avg_sum_resids <- (1/50000)*tmp  # it is 12, proved
```

Comment: "Word salad" to me: Please explain your notation? What are possible values of $i$? Which symbols represent random variables. Do you assume independence? You mention a posterior something (mean? distribution?) What is the prior? What 'specific number' in title? Bits of `codelike type` look as if they might be R ans/or wome version of Winbugs. Other bits seem not to be.

Comment: @BruceET I have added in my question. $y_{i}$ is independent since they are from different hospitals. The specific number is the "number of $y_{i}$", which is 12 in this example.

Comment: Apply the Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: @whuber I tried to answer my question, yet it seems that I used an additional condition and no use of Central Limit Theorem. Could you please see where is wrong in my prove process?

Comment: You assumed Normal distributions, but the variables are not normally distributed, so you didn't prove anything about the situation you have posited.

Comment: @whuber I tried another proof without assuming Normal distributions (yet still no Central Limit Theorem?).

Comment: It appears all you are trying to show is that the variance of a standardized random variable is unity.  That's by design--there's really nothing to prove.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y_i\mid\theta\sim G_\theta$, for $i=1,\dots,N$ (in the original problem statement, $G_\theta$ stands for a $\text{Bin}(n_i,\theta)$ distribution, but this simple result is more general), and suppose that $\mathbb{E}[Y_i^2\mid\theta]<\infty$.
Defining
$$
  R_i := \frac{Y_i - \mathbb{E}[Y_i\mid\theta]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Y_i\mid\theta]}},
$$
it follows immediately (can you see why?) that $\mathbb{E}[R_i\mid\theta]=0$ and $\text{Var}[R_i\mid\theta]=1$. Hence (why?),
$$
  \mathbb{E}[R_i^2\mid\theta]=\mathbb{E}^2[R_i\mid\theta]+\text{Var}[R_i\mid\theta]=1,
$$
and defining $X^2 := \sum_{i=1}^N R_i^2$,
we have that $\mathbb{E}[X^2\mid\theta] = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{E}[R_i^2\mid\theta]=N$ (linearity of the expectation).

Answer (score 0):

- Answer 2019/07/17

We need to prove $E(X^{2})=N$, which is $E[\sum_{i=1}^Nr_i^2]=N$.

So the question becomes to prove the following equation:
$E[r_i^2]=1\tag{1}$ for each $i$.

Proof process:

Because \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E(r_i^2)&=E(\frac{y_{i}-E(y_{i}|\theta)}{\sqrt{Var(y_{i}|\theta)}}*\frac{y_{i}-E(y_{i}|\theta)}{\sqrt{Var(y_{i}|\theta)}})\\&=E(\frac{(y_{i}-E(y_{i}|\theta))^{2}}{Var(y_{i}|\theta)})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

and
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E((y_{i}-E(y_{i}|\theta))^{2})=Var(y_{i}|\theta)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

So
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E(r_i^2)=1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

- Answer 2019/07/16

When considered as a function of random $y_{i}$ for fixed $\theta$, then $r_{i}(\theta)$ has mean 0 and variance 1. Addtionally, if we suppose $r_{i}(\theta)$ are mutually independent standard normal random variables (i.e., I add an extra requirement that $r_{i}(\theta)$ is distributed as Normal), $X^{2}=\sum_ir_i^2$ will has a Chi-square distribution. Since i = 1, 2,...,12 in the example, the mean of Chi-square distributed $X^{2}$ is 12.

However, $r_{i}(\theta)$ is not necessarily "normal" distributed, and I was wondering that I didn't use the Central Limit Theorem when proving.